# Angular looping through items in controller

Tags: angularjs, express

I have a unique scenario where I would like to be able to do angular ng-repeat type logic in the controller. I am using a slidebar on mobile sized screens, which requires the div that makes up the navigation to sit outside the containing div of the website.

This logic is inside of my index.ejs express file:

```
<body>
  <div ng-view></div>
  <div class="sb-slidebar sb-left"></div>
</body>
```

My standard desktop size sidebar does typical ng-repeat logic:

```
<li ng-repeat="items in service"><a href="/service/{{item.shortname}}">{{item.title}}</li></a>
```

Since the slidebar logic is in the core index.ejs express file on the server side, I don't have access to the angular view logic. My solution at the moment is to do logic in the controller based on the url:

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
  var index = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];   
    if(index == 'services'){
       $(".sb-left ul").html("<li>service categories<li>"); 
        } 
     }
```

This approach works; however, I'd the inner html to be updated dynamically, similar to the template tag instead of being hardcoded like it is now.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't use angular directives inside your sidebar. As long as the side bar is inside the ng-app element, you can. And it seems to be.

Comment: You can do that with directive, even if you don't have ng-app attribute but bootstrap manually on document. I am doing that with my ui-router to provide static sidebar that stays on page all the time.